# Black UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have been learning how to use UICollection view. I made a new UICollectionView Controller and identified the collectionview cell as "Cell" in the main.storyboard. I am getting a black screen whenever I tap on the UICollectionView controller (through the TapBar Controller) I am currently using Firebase to import/export data. 
Thank you for your help!

```
  class UserCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
        var databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        var usersDict = NSDictionary?()

        var userNameArray = [String]()
        var userImageArray = [String]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            self.databaseRef.child("user_profile").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock :{
                (snapshot) in
                self.usersDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                for(userId,details) in self.usersDict! {
                    let img = details.objectForKey("profile_pic_small") as! String
                    let name = details.objectForKey("name") as! String
                    let firstName = name.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")[0]
                    self.userImageArray.append(img)
                    self.userNameArray.append(firstName)
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }


            })

        }
            override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
                return 1
            }

            override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return self.userImageArray.count
            }

            override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            return cell


                let imageUrl = NSURL(string: userImageArray[indexPath.row])
                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!)

                cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.userName.text = userNameArray[indexPath.row]

                return cell
        }

    }
```

Comment: You never set a size for the cells: `sizeForItemAtIndexpath`. Also, your code had a typo: `self` instead of `elf`. Check if your `userImageArray` has items.

Comment: The image array has the URL value, and I don't think there is any "elf" since i could run the program without crashing. I made the cell size through the storyboard, but does it have to do with the color of the CollectionViewController regardless?

Comment: You question is simply a matter of you not performing basic debugging. Download and play with [the UIViewController demo app from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: you should change the color of your collectionView, and also dispatch to main queue for your `reloadData()`. And use more guard statement to unwrapped all your optionals

Answer (score 0):

Place a UIView in the cell(set its constraints to 0,0,0,0 with respect to cell) and then later add imageView and label to it. Also don't forget to conform the delegates and data source.